# Import opencart customers to magento

Tags: php, magento, opencart, password-encryption

How we can import customers from opencart to magento. Some extensions are available to migrate all the data which are expensive.

Products and categories can be done manually but i am not able to migrate the customers data.
I believe if we are able to change the md5 password encryption to sha1 in magento we can achieve this. please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to overwrite 1 model and 1 helper to change how encrpytion is handled in Magento Community Edition:

part of **config.XML** file:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <customer>
            <rewrite>
                <customer>Momodule_Encryption_Model_Customer</customer>
            </rewrite>
        </customer>
    </models>
    <helpers>
        <core>
            <encryption_model>Mymodule_Encryption_Model_Encryption</encryption_model>
        </core>
        <mymodule_encryption>
            <class>Yes_Encryption_Helper</class>
        </mymodule_encryption >
    </helpers>
</global>
```

and you need to overwrite CustomerController so the proper encryption method is used when user is loggin in or creating an account:

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Mymodule_Encryption before="Mage_Customer">Mymodule_Encryption</Mymodule_Encryption>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
```

As for the part for customer import you can easly work on models and parse XML / CSV data from your other store.